# How to handle big component in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I have a generic component for Address from external library I do not have access to. Inside there are multiple inputs like street, postal code, city etc. How to add support for it with react-hook-form? I cannot use Connector because it handles only one field at time. Here I need to register multiple fields, something like address.street, address.postalCode, address.city and also handle validation for each of them. Is is possible somehow?

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="address" // ?
  render={({
    field: { value },
    fieldState: { error },
    formState,
  }) => (
    <Address
      street={value.street}
      city={value.city}
      ...
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 'external library I do not have access to'.

How did you install this library? It might be available in your node_modules folder. Did you check?

Comment: I mean it is in node_modules and I cannot modify it so I need to add support of react-hook-form on parent component